# Using JavaScript to sort divs based upon content & sorting empty divs to the end

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

The code below shows my current workings. the commented out line sorts my divs but leaves the empty divs at the top.

the 4 lines above do not make a difference

I think I'm missing something really simple here

```
//Group 1
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs7 = $('.group1').sort(function getSort(a, b) {
        if($(a).find(a).text() === "") return 1;
        if($(b).find(b).text() === "") return -1;
        if($(a).find(a).text() === $(b).find(b).text()) return 0;
        return $(a).find(a).text() < $(b).find(b).text()) ? -1 : 1;
        //return String.prototype.localeCompare.call($(a).text().toLowerCase(), $(b).text().toLowerCase());
    });
```

Comment: _"the 4 lines above do not make a difference"_ - Because `$(a).find(a)` doesn't make any sense at all... Why do you search `a` in the descendants of `a`? o.O

Comment: And you really should store the result of `.text()` in a variable and use that variable for the comparisons

Comment: also, you should share a `div` for example

Comment: Here's how to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/3d12tu6e/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:

```
//Group 1
    var alphabeticallyOrderedDivs7 = $('.group1').sort(function getSort(a, b) {
        //Assuming $(a).text() and $(b).text() is the content of the div
        return $(a).text() < $(b).text() ? 1 : $(a).text() > $(b).text() ? -1 : 0;
    });
```